# Changing font size of one cell in excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am working on a project that writes data to an Excel file.

Everything is finished now, however I need a few cells with a bigger size than the rest (title, etc).

I have read about this about the internet, but I keep having the same problem: when I execute my code (see below for what I have tried), everything in the worksheet becomes larger.

What I already have tried:

```
worksheet.Rows[1].Cells[7].Style.Font.Size = 20; 

worksheet.get_Range("A7", "A7").Style.Font.Size = 20;
```

None of this seems to work; what is the correct way to increase a cell's font size?

Comment: @Arnout You can add a new answer to this question and accept it (if you decide to stick around for another day or two). [This is encouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it)

Answer (score 14):

I had to use:

```
worksheet.get_Range("A7", "A7").Cells.Font.Size = 20;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data is consistent and will always be written to the same cells then this is the simplest solution - works well for *product details / contact info* type exporting

```
// set cell A7
worksheet.get_Range("A7", "A7").Font.Size = 20;

// set cells A7, A8
worksheet.get_Range("A7", "A8").Font.Size = 20;

// set cells A7, B7
worksheet.get_Range("A7", "B7").Font.Size = 20;

// set cells A7, A8, B7, B8
worksheet.get_Range("A7", "B8").Font.Size = 20;
```

If the data varies and will sometimes be written to multiple rows/columns then something like this is more simple - works well for *dataset / shopping list* type exporting

```
int RowNum;
int ColNum;

// some code to set variables

worksheet.Cells[RowNum, ColNum].Font.Size = 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use:

```
worksheet.Range["A7"].Style.Font.Size = 20;
```

edit: sorry, wrong brackets

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Gives this error:

"Non-invocable member 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.Range' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: If I use:  
worksheet.get_Range("A7").Style.Font.Size = 20;

it still gives my whole sheet a size of 20

Answer (score 1):

When working with interop excel, try not to write your code with "two dots" in order to [clean interop excel objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects/159419#159419).
This also helps having your code more readable. 
Anyway, to answer your question, and using what I have pointed out... all you have to do is:

```
//Declare your variables
Application excel = null;
Workbook excelworkBook = null;
Range excelCellrange = null;
Worksheet worksheet = null;
Font excelFont =null;

//start your application
excel = new Application();
try
{
   ...
   //your code goes here...
   excelCellrange = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[1,7],worksheet.Cells[1,7]];
   excelFont = excelCellrange.Font;
   excelfont.Size = 20;
   ...
   ...
}
catch(Exception ex){
}
finally{
   //here put something to clean the interop objects as the link above.
   ...
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelfont);
   ...
}
```